# How to delete <div class="adsSpRect">....</div> in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to delete the div element that has "adsSpRect" class in the variable in sample.js.

```
<div class="adsSpRect" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 0;">
<div class="div-heading">Ad</div>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7527113112850374" data-ad-slot="4179547001" data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

The code which I have written is below

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

request(
    {
        uri: "http://example.com",
    }, 
    function(error, response, body) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body); 
        //console.log(typeof $); --> function

        $("#contents").each(function() { 
            let link = $(this);
            let data = link.html() //I think div.adsSpRect is here
```

Could you kindly tell me how to delete "div.adsSpRect" elemtnt?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.adsSpRect').remove()`

Comment: @connexo Should I paste the code into my code?
document.querySelector('.adsSpRect').remove()
ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Next time, consider adding the relevant tags to your question. `document` being undefined can only mean you are asking server-side JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const htmlData = `<div class="adsSpRect" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 0;">
<div class="div-heading">Ad</div>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7527113112850374" data-ad-slot="4179547001" data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>`;

const final = htmlData
  .replace(/<div class="adsSpRect" style="margin: 10px 0 20px 0;">/, "")
  .trim();

console.log(final);
```